# ¿Cómo se traduce "lexifier" al español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, lingüística

Me refiero al término lingüístico "lexifier" que, según [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexifier) significa

> the language that provides the basis for the majority of a pidgin or creole language's vocabulary (lexicon)

es decir,

> la lengua que proporciona la base de la mayoría del léxico de una lengua pidgin o criolla.

Se me ocurre, "lexificador", pero no he encontrado esta palabra en el diccionario de la RAE.

Comment: A lexifier is the language that provides the basis for the majority of a pidgin or creole language's vocabulary (lexicon).[1] Often this language is also the dominant, or superstrate language, = idioma de base para una lengua criolla ou pidgin.

Answer (score 2):

Los neologismos técnicos tardan en entrar en el DRAE (excepto *[cederrón](https://dle.rae.es/cederr%C3%B3n)*, que ya ni se usa).

Algo que se puede aprovechar en la propia Wikipedia es comprobar los enlaces a la página correspondiente en otros idiomas latinos. En este caso únicamente aparece en portugués como [lexificador](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexificador).

Pero esto anima a buscar *lexificador* en documentos académicos en español, y parece que su uso con el mismo sentido que *lexifier* es [bastante común](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?q=lexificador).

Answer (score 1):

El término correcto y utilizado seria "Lengua Lexificadora".

En *Español* aparece como término compuesto "Lengua lexificadora" presente al menos en libros y estudios anteriores al año 2008, como idioma que proporciona la base para la mayor parte del vocabulario de un idioma criollo. Así se habla entre otros de;

- La lengua lexificadora del Español  para hablas criollas que tienen su base en el Español.
  Como el "afrocostarricense", el "afroboliviano"
- La lengua lexificadora del Francés para hablas criollas que tienen su base en el Francés.
  El criollo de origen Francés de Louisiana, el "Kouri-Vini", no confundir con el criollo de Luisiana, cajun, descendientes de exiliados de Acadia (Canada).

Se puede decir que  el "*Pidgin*", se entiende como habla precursora y se suele traducir en Español como "Habla ó Lengua Macarronica". Así, una vez que esta se transmitió a la siguiente generación como "lingua franca" (quienes fueron considerados los primeros hablantes nativos de la nueva gramática), podría clasificarse efectivamente como lengua criolla .

Por otra parte esta el término "Atrición", Ammerlaan (1991, p. 21), como “*la percepción del declive en el conocimiento lingüístico, o el control sobre ese conocimiento, basado en la comparación de una situación en el pasado y en el presente*”.
En lingüística también se habla de atrición, desgaste o erosión lingüística.

Diego M.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la fuente de toda esta información? ¿Y qué tiene que ver el último párrafo con la pregunta?

Comment: El concepto de "Lengua lexificadora" ya lo puedes ver en este libro del año 2008, "Mestizaje lingüístico en los Andes: Génesis y Estructura de una lengua mixta"
Escrito por Jorge Arsenio Gómez Rendón. En el libro se habla del concepto de la "Media Lengua y el proceso lingüístico importante de relexificacion.

Comment: La lengua lexificadora es la lengua de base para la creación de un pidgin un hablar criollo: francês para el criollo haitiano, el português para el cabo verdiano, etc. –

Answer (score -1):

### Lexicalizar

tr. Ling. Hacer que un elemento lingüístico pase a formar parte del sistema léxico de la lengua.

### Lexicografía

f. Técnica de componer léxicos o diccionarios.

### Lexicógrafo, fa

m. y f. Persona dedicada profesionalmente a la lexicografía.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, pero estas palabras no corresponden a la definición que he citado en la pregunta.